# Is it possible to create a pre-filled select list field with Drush?

Tags: 7, entities, drush

The syntax to create fields is on https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/field/field-create/

For those it works:

Images:

`drush field-create article img,image,image_image`

Text fields:

`drush field-create user address,text,text_textfield --entity_type=user`

text long:

`drush field-create user address,text_long,text_textarea --entity_type=user`

Decimal:

`drush field-create user userpoints,number_decimal,number_textfield --entity_type=user`

Boolean:

`drush field-create content haspurchase,list_boolean`

Is there a way to create a select list field pre-filled with values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create select field also from drush command. Just type the command from drupal root directory `drush field-create content_type_name` and hit enter key and follow the instruction. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Copy the last output which is edit url of your field where you can  refinement your field.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. Can you give an example how to pre-fill the field name_class (e.g. with samurai, ninja, sake)? I was able to create the field, but is there a way to pre-populate it using Drush? The idea is that the user enters some information (in this case fields of an object) in a webform and the result is drush code

Comment: There is nothing about option creation in the documentation of drush field-create command. You can check here https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/field/field-create/ This is only what this command provide.

Comment: i see. thanks. i guess than its not doable without customisation